# Which is more common in Europe - applying for a 'PHD Program' or coming up with a research Q? I still don't fully understand the application process

Tags: phd, research-process, application, europe, deadlines

Do I keep visiting website like 'find a PHD' which have advertisements of PHD programs and their respective application deadlines?

And would these be considered 'pre-designed' programs with a broader/general curriciulum? as opposed to developing my own research proposal and writing to random professors to see if they will take me on? What is the exact difference here?

I have a general topic in mind but I'm struggling to understand how 'general' and how 'specific' to be when applying. Part of the reason is due to the fact that I am also struggling to define my research question/topic.

Yes I know these are very general questions but I'm a bit lost here. I am well aware that a PHD is not the road to Damascus as some people may idealise it, but it is something I wish to try and which I believe could be a good fit for me - I'm nearly 31 and time is running out.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Europe is, (unfortunately in your case), quite heterogeneous in how that works. Can you narrow it by country perhaps? For instance, for the case of Germany, you would not look for "PhD programs" but rather for open positions as scientific employees that are suitable for writing a PhD thesis while holding the position.

Comment: In addition to DCTLib's suggestion, it would also be good to specify your field - in my university PhD projects can range from almost entirely pre-defined (typically lab sciences) to almost entirely designed by the candidate (typically Humanities). There are exceptions to the general rules, but it's helpful to know a rough discipline at least.

Comment: @StephenMcMahon thank you for your reply.

My desired and planned discipline is conflict resolution/counter-terrorism/the broader international security and conflict field.